# Irregular table Issue

Tags: c#, console-application

I wonder what I do wrong about that task:

I had to create a table[][,] where I enter from the keyboard number of groups, the number of students in each group and how many subjects they have.

For each student, I had to enter a grade for each subject.

I don't actually where is my mistake.

Because the program I wrote can't show properly full table (f.e. if in a group no. 1 I have 3 students and for a group no. 2 I have 1 student it shows for each group 1 student)

Also I used "float" to calculate the Average of all grades for each group but it shows the integer number.

Can you help me?

I attached the code down below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SpecialTask
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[][,] tab1;
        static int iSub = 0;
        static int iGro = 0;
        static int iStu = 0;
        static int note = 0;
        static int iSum = 0;
        static float fAvg = 0.0f;

        static int Subjects(string sSubjects)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number of subjects (2-4):");
            }
            while ((!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out iSub)) || (iSub < 2) || (iSub > 4));
            return iSub;
        }

        static int Groups(string sGroups)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number of groups (1-3):");
            }
            while ((!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out iGro)) || (iGro < 1) || (iGro > 3));
            return iGro;
        }

        static int Students(string sStudents)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number of students(1-5): ");
            }
            while ((int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out iStu) == false) || (iStu < 1) || (iStu > 5));
            return iStu;
        }

        static int Notes(string sNotes)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a note (2-5): ");
            }
            while ((!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out note)) || (note < 2) || (note > 5));
            return note;
        }

        static void TabData()
        {

            int i, j, k;
            Subjects("Please enter a number of subjects (2-4):");
            Groups("Please enter a number of groups (1-3):");
            tab1 = new int[iGro][,];

            for (i = 0; i < iGro; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Group NO.{0}", 1 + i);
                Students("Please enter a number of students(1-5): ");
                tab1[i] = new int[iStu, iSub];
                for (j = 0; j < iStu; j++)
                {
                    for (k = 0; k < iSub; k++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Student NO.{0}", 1 + j);
                        Console.WriteLine("Subject NO.{0}", 1 + k);
                        tab1[i][j, k] = Notes("Please enter a note (2-5): ");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            for (i = 0; i < iGro; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Group NO.{0}: ", 1 + i);
                for (j = 0; j < tab1.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Student NO.{0}/Group NO.{1}: ",1+ j, 1 + i);
                    for (k = 0; k < iSub; k++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Subject NO.{0}: ", 1 + k);
                        Console.Write(tab1[i][j, k]);
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                }
            }
        }

        static void avgG()
        {
            int i, j, k;
            TabData();
            for (i = 0; i < iGro; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < iStu; j++)
                {
                    for (k = 0; k < iSub; k++)
                    {
                        iSum = iSum + tab1[i][j, k];
                    }
                }
                fAvg = iSum / iSub;
                Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + iSum);
                Console.WriteLine("Average of all grades for Group NO. {0}: {1}", i, fAvg);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            avgG();
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As part of your learning and practice, this is a *great* time to start familiarizing yourself with the use of your debugger.  It allows you to step through the code line by line as it executes, observing the exact runtime behavior of your code and even the exact runtime values of all of your variables as they change from one line to the next.  When you do this, where specifically do you first encounter an operation or line of code which produces an unexpected result?  What were the inputs to that line of code?  What was the result?  What was the expected result?  Why?

Comment: Please explain what `static int[][,] tab1;` is meant to contain.

Comment: Int[NumberOfGroups][Students,Subcjects]